# In angularjs ng-change="chk(query)" call function when space is hit after typing word

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using following code to take input from user and search the term

the problem is that if I press any word function gets called but  when I press spacebar it is not calling the function so I want if user enters space then also the function should get called

```
<input ng-model="query" ng-change="chk(query)"  placeholder="Search..">
```

so please can anyone suggest me with the solution please

Thank you

I tried to use `ng-trim="false"` but not working

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using AngularJS 1.1.1+ in order to use `ng-trim="false"`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SUtfE/

Comment: Its working in Your example but in my project its not working I am unable to sort what is the problem so please can you suggest what should be done